# Is it possible to cast a byte into the empty string using `string()` in Go?

Tags: string, go, type-conversion

Is it possible to cast a byte into the empty string in Go? I've tried with `string(0)`, but the result is a `string` of length 1:

```
emptyString := ""
nullByte := 0
fmt.Printf("%T, %v - %T, %v", emptyString, len(emptyString), string(nullByte), len(string(nullByte)))
```

**Output**:

```
string, 0 - string, 1
```

The reason I want to do this, is that I got a function that takes a `byte` and casts it into a `string`, and I want to supply the empty string  to this function.

Comment: First, there is no casting at all in Go, only type conversion. Second, your question doesn't make sense... you're trying to cast/convert something to nothing? Can you show the actual example you're dealing with?

Comment: After re-reading a few times, I'm pretty sure the answer to your question is a simple "no." But it also seems a lot like an XY Problem. If you can explain the larger goal, maybe a solution can be found.

Comment: String is a 2 word struct, byte is just a byte, how are you going to cast it, if first field of string is a pointer? You can cast byte slice into string, yes, because their structures are same (except cap field). And then, "" equals nil pointer (uninitiated byte slice), where 0 is already something contained in

Comment: @Flimzy - what’s the difference between casting and type conversion? In both cases, you have a value of some type and change its type?

Comment: @Shuzheng: https://techdifferences.com/difference-between-type-casting-and-type-conversion.html

Comment: I'm not sure I totally agree with the techdifferences.com article. Each language tends to define its own terms around types, casts, conversions, and so on: it's a bit awkward to try to lump them all into one global definition. It's generally true that a "cast" is an explicit request for some kind of conversion, regardless of the programming language. In that sense, int(float32(1.2)) could contain two "casts". It's just that Go doesn't *call* them that. See [the spec](https://golang.org/ref/spec) for details.

Comment: Converting a non-empty `[]byte` to a `string` yields a non-empty `string`. That should not come as a surprise.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The empty string `""` has 0 bytes. If you have one byte and you convert that to `string`, the result string will have a single `rune` that equals to that 1 byte (which may even be encoded to multiple bytes in UTF-8). [Spec: Conversions:](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Conversions)

> Converting a signed or unsigned integer value to a string type yields a string containing the UTF-8 representation of the integer.

So obviously you can't convert a byte to a string having 0 bytes, whatever that byte is. Converting the "most promising candidate": `byte(0)` would result in a string with a single `0` byte: `"\x00"` or `[]byte{0}` (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/JCK-uu1ecGg)).

Also note that in your example you're converting an `int` (type of `nullByte` is `int`), but the same quoted part of the spec applies.